# На протяжении. Как объяснить написание Я

Tags: орфография, корень-слова

Нам задали списать текст и объяснить написание вставленных букв. Букву-то я вставила, а вот объяснить не могу. Может, этот корень надо просто запомнить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> *На протяжении*. Как объяснить написание Я?

***Протяжение*** — сост. по глаг. ***протЯгиваться***.

В однокоренном с *протяжением* слове гласная *Я* находится под ударением.